# Mac Surname vs Macsurname vs MacSurname in Scottish- what is the difference?

Tags: etymology

In Scottish names, is there ANY significance to Mac [space] SurnameCapitalized or MacSurnameCapitalized or Macsurnamenocap?  They clearly evolved from the same relationship at some time.  Are they merely flukes of a world becoming more writing-centric over time and inventing new rules?  Or is there a rhyme or reason for it?

Comment: Why leave out other variants?  McCown ; M<sup>c</sup>Cown ; I didn't find Unicode for c with ~ under it.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/543272/why-were-scottish-irish-names-once-rendered-with-apostrophes-instead-of-mac

Comment: @KateBunting I've never encountered 'mac-space-surname', and I *am* scottish.